# I terminated a process and now the Amazon website doesn't work. How can I fix this?

Tags: aws

There was a file that kept reappearing in my Documents folder after deletion. I started to terminate processes using Activity Monitor, to see if I could establish what was causing the issue. I discovered that the issue was caused by the graphic tablet software, but I now have another problem: when I browse the Amazon website, when I click on products, the product doesn't list properly. Everything above 'Frequently bought together' is missing. This happens for about half the products that I browse. I tried running the Disk Utility First Aid, but it didn't help. Is this Amazon issue a result of me terminating processes? If so, how can I get those processes back? I've tried rebooting but to no avail.

Comment: Ref : https://superuser.com/questions/1725986/why-does-a-file-keep-reappearing-in-my-documents-folder?noredirect=1#comment2667663_1725986

Comment: Hi Tetsujin. I'm not sure that the referenced page helps with this issue, but thanks for responding anyway. Are you able to help with this issue?

Comment: Which browser shows this problem? Have you tried _another_ browser in your troubleshooting? On my Mac I use Safari, Google Chrome and Firefox. Does it happen in all of these browsers?

Comment: My main browser is Safari but I tried using Chrome and there was the same issue. But this morning the problem is all but gone. I tried viewing several Amazon items using both Safari and Chrome and only once did I get that same issue. Thanks for your input.